# Feeds - importing from 2 csv

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

i'm having issue with Feeds module, i already imported my csv but the images are in a different csv file, (the images are urls from old site) in the first csv i have and ID for every gallery and ofc this ID is inside the csv where are the images. Is it possible somehow to update and attach these images to my node ? I guess i need to work with that ID somehow. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you add a unique identifier/primary key column to both csv's, you can map that column as the GUID (under Processor > Mapping tab of the specific feed importer config) and set the Feeds importer to update the nodes 
[image: from the Processor > Settings tab as shown in the attached screenshot]

You may need to use the [Feeds Tamper module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) to properly parse out the subfields of data for the images/files (such as alt text), downloading them from your legacy site, and uploading to the new site.